# Grub2 Timeout is Too Short

Tags: 14.04, grub2, timeout

I wanted to set grub2 timeout to 0 seconds so that it skips the boot menu screen. In 14.04, it doesn't do that so I set the timeout to 0.5 seconds. Now it's too fast for me to select which OS to use and holding down shift doesn't work.  I have a live CD but I have no idea what to do.  Any help?

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to what you are trying to do - if you had set the Grub menu to 0, would it not go by even faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find the necessary instructions to boot the live-CD, mount your hard disk, and edit /etc/default/grub at:  [changing grub timeout using live cd (or otherwhise)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650021)